# Slow processing of unique permutation in arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi Im trying to get the unique permutations for a list of strings in PHP7 but finding it really slow with larger lists. In theory the list of items could easily stretch to 15.

```
 //runs quickly returns more results
 function listPermutations($items, $perms = array()) {

    if (empty($items)) {
        $this->final[] = $perms;

    } else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
            $newitems = $items;
            $newperms = $perms;
            list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
            array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
            $this->listPermutations($newitems, $newperms);
        }
    }

    return $this->final;
}

//runs really slow, removed duplicate list orderings
function listUniquePermutations($items, $perms = array()) {

    if (empty($items)) {
        //this is much faster than if(!in_array($perms, $this->final))
        if(!in_array(join('-', $perms), $this->existing)) {
            $this->existing[] = join('-', $perms);
            $this->final[] = $perms;
        }

    } else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
            $newitems = $items;
            $newperms = $perms;
            list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
            array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
            $this->listUniquePermutations($newitems, $newperms);
        }
    }

    return $this->final;
}
```

Ok so the first method is quite quick but then I'm running a second process on double the amount of permutations.

```
/** @test */
public function itShould_createListTwoUniquePermutationsForOrderItems()
{
    $array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

    $items = (new ItemPermutations())->listUniquePermutations($array);
    $this->assertEquals(count($items), 181440);
}
```

The second method can get me unique permutations but takes 5 minutes even when switching to search for a string in array rather than array in array

```
/** @test */
public function itShould_createListTwoUniquePermutationsForOrderItems()
{
    $array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

    $items = (new ItemPermutations())->listUniquePermutations($array);
    $this->assertEquals(count($items), 181440);
}
```

What language would perform this processing faster. Is python the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the language, it's the code. By storing every permutation you generate and searching that list to see if a value is unique your code is running in what is probably `O(n*log(n))` or even `O(n²)` time, not to mention using a *boatload* of memory. So no matter what language you convert this to it's still going to be painfully slow.

However, there are algorithms to generate permutations and combinations in constant `O(n)` time, or nearly so. [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm), for example.

However, you're compounding the problem by having duplicate entries in your input which inherently introduces a 2x duplication rate that's not easy to deal with. Once again you're stuck with the `O(n*log(n))` or `O(n²)` task of comparing every entry with every other.

So if you can reduce your problem space to lists of *unique* items you're going to need to find a way to deal with generated duplicates more efficiently.

Anyhow, I happen to have recently written a small library that implements Heap's Algorithm. You can find it [on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/wrossmann/pc-iters), but here's the PermutationIterator:

```
class PermutationIterator {
    /**
     * Given a set of items generate all possible unique arrangements
     * of items. Uses Heap's Algorithm.
     * 
     * @param   array   $set    The set of items on which to operate.
     */
    public static function iterate($set) {
        $state = array_fill(0, count($set), 0);

        yield $set;

        for($i=0, $c=count($set); $i<$c; ) {
            if($state[$i] < $i) {
                if($i % 2 == 0) {
                    self::swap($set, 0, $i);
                } else {
                    self::swap($set, $state[$i], $i);
                }
                yield $set;
                $state[$i]++;
                $i = 0;
            } else {
                $state[$i] = 0;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap array items.
     * @ignore
     */
    protected static function swap(&$arr, $a, $b) {
        $t = $arr[$a];
        $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
        $arr[$b] = $t;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
foreach( PermutationIterator::iterate(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']) as $comb ) {
    printf("%s\n", json_encode($comb));
}
```

And `time php example.php | wc -l`:

```
362880

real    0m1.853s
user    0m0.027s
sys     0m1.791s
```

Comment: I suppose if you *had* to deal with the duplicates you could probably store the results in an ordered set and use a binary search to find the ideal insertion point for a new item, which would also be the location of a duplicate record. Something like that would be more along the lines of `O(log(n))`, but then you also have the overhead of doing thousands of mid-set insertions. YMMV

Comment: There is a requirement for duplicate items in the input array, but thanks I'll check this out.

Comment: @SamanthaMountford you really nerd-sniped me on this one as I've been thinking on it for nearly two weeks. I wrote a really messy Red-Black Tree implementation, tweaked it to drop duplicates, and fed the permutations [with duplicates] into it. 362880 perms ingested in 15058ms, 181440 perms out in 2266ms, and 145MB peak memory usage.